# What is the shortcut string representation of the move to file refactor in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-keybinding

Refactor actions can be bound to shortcuts like seen in https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/refactoring

```
{
  "key": "shift+ctrl+e",
  "command": "editor.action.codeAction",
  "args": {
    "kind": "refactor.extract.constant",
    "preferred": true,
    "apply": "ifSingle"
  }
}
```

I'd like to bind my <kbd>F2</kbd> to move a symbol to a file (As in WebStorm).  What "kind" value should I use?

Comment: you can create an issue for the vsc doc pages (it has its own repo) to get explanation for all refactor arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about the code action that [the builtin TypeScript/JavaScript language support extension](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/tree/main/extensions/typescript-language-features) provides, then from searching `['"]refactor\..*move` in https://github.dev/microsoft/vscode with regex search mode, I'm pretty confident you're looking for `refactor.move.newFile`, which is defined in the `actions` property in [its package manifest](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/main/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.json), and in English, its title is localized to "Move to a new file", and its description to "Move the expression to a new file.".